Snagit Intercepting Shift-DownArrow
When editing files, I often need to highlight several lines of code with shift-down-arrow.
Snagit (2024.2.2 Build 3491) on Windows 11 is intercepting that.  I can escape out, or to find out what it's doing, if I highlight an area, a box pops up that says "Scroll vertically or horizontally to start".
I know that we can change the keys to intercept in SnagIt, and I have that set to the "Print Screen" button, which is once again working after Microsoft changed something a while back.
This is my "Hot Keys" configuration screen:

Where do I go in SnagIt to turn off or change the intercept of Shift-Down-Arrow?

According to https://www.techsmith.com/learn/tutorials/snagit/snagit-hotkeys/, Send Backward is Command+Down Arrow, and Send to Back is Option+Command+Down Arrow, and no others use Down Arrow. You might see if there's a free alternative you like, though you might have paid for Snagit.

@DrMoishePippik No thanks, I love SnagIt in general.

I did open a support ticket with TechSmith, but I think I finally saw the settings called "Presets" rather than them telling me what to do.  (However, I went through a complete re-install at their request, I surely hope that was not necessary.)
If the "Presets" are not showing, you have to click the "gear" symbol to the left of the word "Presets".
Highlighted in yellow is where the Shift-Num-2 was being set, so I could finally change it.

